# Optional/multiple template URL in single directive Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

Can I have a option between two template URL. Something like :

```
angular.factory('SAMPLE',function(){
    return {
        getnDetails:function($http){            
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            });
    }
)};

angular.directive() {    
     controller : function($scope) {

     SAMPLE. getnDetails().sucess(){

     }.error() {

        templateURL: "zbx.html"
     }   

 templateUrl : "xyz.html"
 }
```

such that when my http request is an error load  entirely different template. What would be the best way to something like this.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include` is probably your friend here. A partial (hopefully syntactically correct) example:

```
angular('app').directive('coolDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.template = 'b.html';

      if ($scope.condition) {
        $scope.template = 'a.html';
      }
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="template"></div>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to select different templates.  The key is that templateUrl can be a function which accepts the element and the attributes.

In my HTML

```
<my-directive template="test-template.html"></my-directive>
```

In my Directive

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {

    var path = '/app/templates/';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return path + tAttrs.template + '.html';
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

                  // whatever...
        }

    };
})
```

I like this approach because it allows me to have a common directive for all the logic, but control from my HTML the template format to use to display the results.

According to the Angular Directive page.

> Note: You do not currently have the ability to access scope variables
>   from the templateUrl function, since the template is requested before
>   the scope is initialized.

That said, the solution you were striving for was to open a totally different template if there was an error.  In that case you'd want to use the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) to redirect to an error page, not simply load a different template.  Or perhaps have an error handling directive in your main template which opens an error modal on any page.

Hope that info helps you or someone else.